Migrating from Vue-CLI to Vite getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" when deploying
When using Vue-CLI, users would get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" each time we deployed an update until we included a base tag in the index.html file.
Now that we are migrating to Vite.js, if we deploy the site and a user merely refreshes the site (as opposed to loading it from a clean cache) they will get the above error again (with a blank white screen).
I have experimented with deploying with and without the  tag as well as
export default defineConfig({
base: 'https://foo.bar'
...
})
in vite.config.js but with no success, it doesn't "replace" what's already on their browser.
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Try to find an official guide regarding the migration and maybe some Github issues.

Thank you. I initially followed the vueschool migration guide as prescribed by vue-cli ( https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-vue-cli-to-vite/ ) and I've looked up and down the Vite site. But I can't seem to find a solution to this particular issue.
